# How to read some lines from a file and output them with changed and added characters into another file?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I wrote a batch script for my development environment variables, but have some troubles because I'm not familiar with Windows batch scripts.

This is what I tried so far:

```
echo window._env_ = { > ./env-config.js
findstr /v # .env >> ./env-config.js
echo } >> ./env-config.js
```

It outputs this:

```
window._env_ = { 
REACT_APP_SITE_TITLE=MyWebsite
REACT_APP_SITE_URL=http://localhost:3000
BROWSER=none
REACT_APP_API_ENDPOINT=http://localhost:5000
}
```

These are the environment variables stored in the file `.env` which I want to write into the file `env-config.js`:

```
#
# Website Title
REACT_APP_SITE_TITLE=MyWebsite
#
# Website URL
REACT_APP_SITE_URL=https://my-website-url.org
#
# Define if the Browser auto-open at react start
BROWSER=none
#
# Define the API Endpoint for the Backend
REACT_APP_API_ENDPOINT=http://localhost:5000
```

The final `env-config.js` should look like this:

```
window._env_ = {
REACT_APP_SITE_TITLE: "MyWebsite",
REACT_APP_SITE_URL: "https://my-website-url.org",
BROWSER: "none",
REACT_APP_API_ENDPOINT: "http://localhost:5000",
}
```

So what I need to do is to set the variable values in the output in quotes, change `=` to `:` and add a comma at the end. But I can´t find a solution combined with `findstr`.

Does anyone have an idea how to get the wanted output from the input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**FINDSTR** outputs all lines containing a searched string or a string matched by a regular expression respectively with the usage of option `/V` all lines **NOT** containing a searched string or a string matched by a regular expression (inverted result). Therefore **FINDSTR** can be used to filter out the lines starting with `#`, but the other lines are output as stored in the file `.env` which is of no help here as the lines not starting with `#` should be written reformatted into the file `env-config.js`.

The solution is using a **FOR /F** loop to process each line in the text file `.env` and output the lines not starting with `#` with command **ECHO** with the values of interest reformatted as required redirected into the file `env-config.js`.

The batch file solution with just a single command line:

```
@(echo window._env_ = {& (for /F "eol=# tokens=1* delims==" %%I in (.env) do @echo %%I: "%%J",) & echo })> .\env-config.js
```

`@` at beginning of a command line executed just once (everything after first `@`) or multiple times (`echo %%I: "%%J",` inside the loop) during the batch file execution prevents the output of the command line after parsing and before executing it. Batch files contain usually at top `@echo off` to turn off command echo mode for all further command lines in the batch file and prevent also the output of this first command line.

The opening round bracket `(` after first `@` defines a command block which ends with the last closing parenthesis `)` left to redirection operator `>`. The Windows Command Processor `cmd.exe` processing the batch file opens first the file `env-config.js` in the **current directory** as defined with the relative path `.\` for write operations and truncates the file to zero length if that file exists already because of everything output to handle **STDOUT** (standard output) during execution of the command block should be redirected into this file. The file is kept open until the execution of all commands inside the command block finished.

The ampersand `&` outside a double quoted argument string is interpreted as **unconditional AND** command operator. For more details about unconditional and conditional (`&&` and `||`) command operators see [single line with multiple commands using Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25344009/3074564).

The command block on a single command line contains here three commands which are executed once.

**ECHO** is different to most other [Windows commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/windows-commands) as it does not interpret a space character as argument string separator, but as character to output. For that reason there is no space between `{` and `&` to avoid that this space is output by **ECHO** resulting in a trailing space in the file `env-config.js`.

Which commands are executed can be seen easier by splitting the single command line version up into multiple command lines.

```
@echo off
(
    echo window._env_ = {
    for /F "eol=# tokens=1* delims==" %%I in (.env) do echo %%I: "%%J",
    echo }
)> .\env-config.js
```

The inner command block defined by `(` left to `for` and ending with `)` after `,` is not needed anymore in this case because of the line termination defines where the **FOR** command line executing multiple times the command **ECHO** ends. In the single command line version the two round brackets are needed to let `cmd` know where the command line to execute by **FOR** on each loop iteration ends.

There is first written into the opened file `env-config.js` the string `window._env_ = {` output by command **ECHO** with carriage return and line-feed as line termination (18 characters/bytes).

Next the file `.env` in **current directory** is opened for read operations because of option `/F` of command **FOR** and the file name `.env` neither enclosed in `"` (processing of string) nor in `'` (processing of captured output of a command line).

The default behavior of **FOR /F** on processing the lines of a text file is

- ignoring empty lines which are lines not containing any character than the line ending characters carriage return and line-feed,
- splitting the line up into substrings using normal space and horizontal tab as string delimiters with removal of all leading spaces/tabs from the line,
- looking on first character of first substring on being a semicolon which is the default end of line character in which case the line is not further processed,
- assigning the first space/tab delimited substring not starting with `;` to the specified loop variable and
- executing the command respectively the commands in the command block specified after `do`.

This line splitting behavior is modified with the options `eol=# tokens=1* delims==` specified within `"` to be interpreted as one argument string after option `/F` to

- split up each non-empty line on equal signs as defined with `delims==`,
- ignore all lines starting with the character `#` as defined with `eol=#`,
- whereby two substrings are wanted, the first substring and everything after the equal sign(s) after first substring kept as is without splitting this part of the line up further on equal signs as defined with `tokens=1*` and
- assign the first equal sign delimited substring to specified loop variable `I` and if there is something more on the line to the next loop variable `J` according to [ASCII table](https://www.asciitable.com/).

So the lines starting with `#` in file `.env` are ignored and on other lines the string left to first (series of) `=` is assigned to the loop variable `I` (name) and everything after first (series of) `=` is assigned to the loop variable `J` (value) which can be also an empty string if there is nothing after first equal sign.

The two strings are output with command **ECHO** with a colon and a space between name and value and with enclosing the value in double quotes and with a comma at end of the line and this output is written with carriage return and line-feed into the opened file `env-config.js`.

Last after all lines of `.env` are processed by **FOR /F** and this file is closed, there is output with **ECHO** the string `}` with the newline characters carriage return and line-feed.

The execution of all commands of the command block is finished with `echo }` and so `cmd` closes the file `env-config.js` containing now all the output characters/bytes.

The **current directory** is not necessarily the directory containing the batch file. So if it is expected that the file `.env` is in the directory of the batch file and the file `env-config.js` should be created also in the directory of the batch file, it would be better to use the following single command line batch file.

```
@(echo window._env_ = {& (for /F "usebackq eol=# tokens=1* delims==" %%I in ("%~dp0.env") do @echo %%I: "%%J",) & echo })> "%~dp0env-config.js"
```

The multi-line version is:

```
@echo off
(
    echo window._env_ = {
    for /F "usebackq eol=# tokens=1* delims==" %%I in ("%~dp0.env") do echo %%I: "%%J",
    echo }
)> "%~dp0env-config.js"
```

`%~dp0` (drive and path of batch file argument 0) expands to the full directory path of the batch file always ending with a backslash and therefore concatenated without one more `\` with the file names `.env` and `env-config.js`.

The **FOR /F** option `usebackq` is used additionally to get the fully qualified file name of the file `.env` in the batch file directory enclosed in `"` interpreted as file name of a text file of which lines to process and not as string to process.

Please note that the directory separator on Windows is `\` and not `/` as on Linux/Mac as described by Microsoft in the documentation about [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file). The usage of `/` instead of `\` in file/folder strings usually work thanks to the automatic correction applied by the Windows I/O functions as explained by the referenced Microsoft documentation page. But there are use cases on which the usage of `/` in a file/folder string results in unexpected behavior as described with two examples in the answer on [How can I check if either or file exists in IF Exist?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68088287/3074564)

For completeness a multi-line batch file which outputs the lines in file `.env` in directory of the batch file into the file `env-config.js` in directory of the batch file without a comma on the last line read from `.env`.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "FirstLine=1"
(
    echo window._env_ = {
    for /F "usebackq eol=# tokens=1* delims==" %%I in ("%~dp0.env") do (
        if not defined FirstLine (echo ,) else set "FirstLine="
        set /P =%%I: "%%J"<nul
    )
    echo(
    echo }
)> "%~dp0env-config.js"
endlocal
```

There can be removed both `%~dp0` to use the current directory instead of the batch file directory.

The **IF** condition results in the output of a string with a comma, a carriage return and a line-feed if the currently processed line is not the first line with data to output read from the file `.env`.

The command **SET** with option `/P` is used here with no environment variable name to output the reformatted data to handle **STDOUT** without a carriage return and line-feed which does not wait for user input because of the device **NUL** is used as **STDIN** (standard input) which cannot be opened to read something.

The additional command line `echo(` results in the output of just carriage return and line-feed to terminate also the last line with data read from `.env` not having a comma at end.

These are special "hacks" not officially documented by Microsoft, but documented in many answers on Stack Overflow and in DosTips forum topics [ECHO. FAILS to give text or blank line - Instead use ECHO/](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=774)

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `call /?` ... explains batch file argument referencing as done with `%~dp0`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

See also the Microsoft documentation about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)).